# Let A be NP-complete and B be NP-hard. Can B be polynomial time reducible to A?

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, np

Let A be NP-complete and B be NP-hard. Can B be polynomial time reducible to A?

Ans: I know it can't be. Would the strong reason be, because NP-Complete is a subset of NP-Hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first look at naming conventions of `NP Hard` and `NP Complete` ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness)):

> **NP-hard**
>  Class of decision problems which are at least as hard as the hardest problems in NP. Problems that are NP-hard do not have to
>   be elements of NP; indeed, they may not even be decidable.
>
> **NP-complete**
>  Class of decision problems which contains the hardest problems in NP. Each NP-complete problem has to be in NP.

`NP-hard`(B) are at least as hard as the hardest problem of `NP`.
Hardest problems of `NP` are `NP-complete`(A).

From these two statements, we can say that **B is at least as hard as A**.

In simpler terms, this means that any algorithm for B immediately gives an algorithm for A. But the inverse is not true, knowing how to solve A doesn't tell us anything about how to solve B. This relation is not symmetric.

This is why NP-hard is not reducible to NP-complete.